# How do I install Wine on Fedora 20?

Tags: fedora, wine

How do I install Wine on Fedora 20? Other versions of Fedora or other Linuces are not an option.

I would prefer to use a package manner, but can also build from source

Comment: Did you try something like `yum search wine`? This lists all packages with `wine` in their name. You could then select the correct package and install it with `yum install <packagename>`eg. `yum install wine`. For the installation you must be root.

Comment: Fedora 20 is past end of life. Use a currently supported Fedora release (30 or 29 today).

Comment: ***Other versions of Fedora or other Linuces are not an option.***

Comment: @Mawg why are other versions of Fedora or Linux not an option? Fedora 20 has been out of date for a long time and the repositories most likely closed down. It will be difficult to maintain as wine has many dependencies and those dependencies need libraries and additional packages that you would have to track down to update and upgrade manually each time. Please take the suggested advice to update or provide a use case as to why it is necessary to remain so out of date. Thank you!

Comment: Because 5 levels of management above me say so. It is Fedora 20 and is going to remain Fedora 20 until the project ends in 3 or 4 years. That is not negotiable. Now, do you have an answer for me?

Comment: First, the project must begin! And that isn't going to happen with Fedora 20.

Comment: Oddly enough, that very thing happened a few years back and the project has been chugging along nicely since then, with no one willing to risk destabilizing by changing a VM which is known to be good.

Comment: You have to understand that running outdated software, however convenient it may seem, is definitely NOT a good idea, management, CEO, head of state of your country, great JuJu on the mountain, whatever, NOT a good idea. That version has not been maintained for at least 4 years! Besides, the wine you will be using will be oudated unless you build it yourself. I would recommend PoL, it allows you to switch between wine versions.

Comment: While I may agree with you, change is ***not** an option. I am working a large government contract, wtiht eh VM aligned across several companies. It's good to point it out, to help future readers, but it won't help me, so I won't be replying to any more such comments (no offence intended).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first adding repositories

```
sudo yum install https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm https://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm
yum update
yum install wine
```

If not work try upgrading to latest fedora it supports lot of new libraries

Comment: RPMfusion doesn't have wine packages for Fedora 20.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you are asking how to use a version of Fedora no longer supported. So you get to do this yourself. Build your own wine packages and all the dependencies.  Make it clear to your management that this is a huge endeavor, and it will require a lot of time and effort to do so.

OR... you could tell management that it would make more sense to use an *actually supported* platform.  RHEL7 was forked from Fedora 19, so it most likely shares a lot of common package versions.  CentOS 7 is a free rebuild of RHEL7. Why not give it a try?  If anything, you might be able to start with CentOS7 SRPMs when you build your Fedora 20 packages you have chosen to take on support for.

**UPDATE:** If you want to build Wine from source, follow [the instructions on its website.](https://wiki.winehq.org/Building_Wine)

Comment: Unless you give details of how to build from source, this reads more like a comment than an answer. Management is intransigent, but, fortunately, @Sage provided a good answer.

Comment: If you are talking about the answer suggesting rpmfusion, you might find that those repos only go back as far as fedora 28.

Comment: I've added a link to how to build wine from source.

Comment: Thanks very much (and upvotes :-)